# Find the center of all circles that touch the $x$-axis and a circle centered at the origin

Tags: geometry, inverse-function, locus, moduli-space

Given a circle $C$ of radius $1$ centered at the origin, I want to determine the locus of the centers of all circles that touch $C$ and the $x$-axis.  This is the red curve in the following [Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e8upuzdtke), where the blue circle touches $C$ and the $x$-axis:

[image]

Let $P=(\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)$ be the point where the blue circle touches $C$. Moving $\ell$ units towards the center of $C$ (the origin) gives the point $Q=(1-\ell)(\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)$. Now a circle around $Q$ touches the $x$-axis when the $y$-coordinate of $Q$ equals $\ell$, so that $Q$ has the same distance to $C$ and to $y=0$:

$$
Q_y=(1-\ell)\cos\alpha \stackrel.= \ell \tag1
$$

This equation is solved by
$$Q_y=\frac{\cos\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha} \tag2$$
It's also easy to compute the $x$-ccordinate of $Q$, which yields $Q$ depending on $\alpha$:
$$
Q=Q(\alpha)=\left(\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}, \frac{\cos\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}\right) \tag3
$$

Where I am stuck is to compute $Q_y$ as a function of $Q_x$, that is find $f$ such that

$$
Q_y = f(Q_x) \tag4
$$

By looking at the plot I guessed
$$
f(t) = \frac12(1-t^2) \tag 5
$$
and indeed $Q$ satisfies $(5)$. It's not surprising that $f$ is a curve or order 2.  **But how to do it without guessing?** I have no idea how to find the inverse of

$$
\alpha \mapsto \frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}
$$
Trying to substitute $\alpha = \arcsin z$ gives
$$
Q(z) = \left(\frac z{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}} , \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}} \right)\tag6
$$
just makes it more complicated...

Comment: No, the red curve is not (a part of) a circle. It's a parabola.

Comment: you're correct, I confused a few things

Comment: It seems you used a too "overkill" method, sometimes simpler is easier!

Comment: There is a second set of solutions, namely the reflection of your red curve in the $x$-axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no idea how to find the inverse of
> $$\alpha \mapsto \frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}$$

When manipulating trig expressions, always be on the lookout to utilise the fundamental Pythagorean identity,
$$\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha=1$$

Note that
$$\sin^2\alpha = 1-\cos^2\alpha = (1+\cos\alpha)(1-\cos\alpha)$$
So
$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha} = \frac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$$

Let
$$u = \frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha} = \frac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$$
Thus
$$u^2 = \left(\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}\right) \left(\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\right)$$
That is,
$$u^2 = \frac{1-\cos\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}$$
which is easy to invert:
$$\cos\alpha = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$

Also,
$$\sin\alpha = \frac{2u}{1+u^2}$$
So
$$\tan\alpha = \frac{2u}{1-u^2}$$
Hence
$$u=\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Answer (score 11):

The radius of a blue circle is $y$. The distance between the centers is $1-y$ (do you see why?). Therefore, $x^2 + y^2 = (1-y)^2$.

Comment: If $y$ is negative, then the radius is $r=-y$ while the distance between the centres is $1-r$ at least when $-1<x<1$, though if $x>1$ or $x<-1$ then  the distance between the centres is $1+r$.

Answer (score 6):

Let the centre of the circle be $C = (h,r).$
since, this circle touches $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ internally,
$|OC| = 1 - r.$
$\implies h^2+r^2 = (1-r)^2.$
$\implies h^2 = 1 - 2r.$
$\implies h = \sqrt{1-2r}$ 
or   $ r = \displaystyle\frac{1-h^2}{2}.$

Answer (score 2):

With the arcsin substitution you had ended up with:

$$Q(z) = \left(\frac z{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}} , \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}} \right)\tag6$$

It looks harder than it really is. You just have to press on:

$$\begin{aligned}
x &= \frac z{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}} \\
\frac z x - 1 &= \sqrt{1-z^2} \\
\frac{z^2}{x^2} - \frac{2 z}{x} + 1 &= 1 - z^2 \\
\left(\frac{1}{x^2} + 1\right)z^2 - \frac{2 z}{x} &= 0 \\
\left(1 + x^2\right)z - 2 x &= 0 \\
z &= \frac{2 x}{1 + x^2}
\end{aligned}$$

(Note that $z = 0$ is a [spurious solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) coming from $z/x - 1 = {\color{red}-}\sqrt{1-z^2}$, which we can disregard.)

Then we evaluate $y$:

$$\begin{aligned}
z &= \frac{2 x}{1 + x^2} \\
z^2 &= \frac{4 x^2}{(1 + x^2)^2} \\
1 - z^2 &= \frac{1 + 2 x^2 + x^4 - 4 x^2}{(1 + x^2)^2} \\
&= \frac{1 - 2 x^2 + x^4}{(1 + x^2)^2} \\
&= \frac{(1 - x^2)^2}{(1 + x^2)^2} \\
\sqrt{1 - z^2} &= \frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^2} \\
y &= \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1-z^2}} \\
&= \frac{(1 + x^2) \sqrt{1-z^2}}{1 + x^2 + (1 + x^2) \sqrt{1-z^2}} \\
&= \frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^2 + 1 - x^2} \\
&= \frac{1 - x^2}{2}
\end{aligned}$$